# Jquery if window width < something and p string > something

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Trying to fix css margin for certain screen width and string length, but for testing purposes made the script alert.

Here is jquery code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var $hn = $('#footcap2');
  if ($(window).width() < 1025) && ($hn.text().length > 12)
    {
alert('Less');
}
else {
alert('More');
}
});
```

No alerts pop up.  Jquery is connected for sure, so I'm guessing i made a mistake somewhere in the syntax. Can someone help me out and show where it is?

Thank you!

Comment: If you have a syntax error, you'll get an error in the JavaScript Console - that should be the first place to look.

Comment: Any errors in your browser's console? And what is `$hn`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 var $hn = $('#footcap2');
if(($(window).width() < 1025) && ($hn.text().length > 12))
{
alert('Less');
}
else 
{
alert('More');
}
});
```

#### Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/robertrozas/qGq69/

Answer (score 3):

You have a syntax error with the parentheses here:

```
if ($(window).width() < 1025) && ($hn.text().length > 12)
   ^                        ^    ^                      ^
```

An `if` condition must be entirely surrounded by a pair of parentheses.

You need this:

```
if ($(window).width() < 1025 && $hn.text().length > 12)
```

[Here it is on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arKg2/).

You should get into the habit of looking at your browser console (press F12) - that would have pointed you straight at the error.